# Precision Set Value

Tags: java

Hey guys so I am a Java student I have the rest of the code working except for 1 line and not exactly sure whats not working.  The error I am getting is a "cannot find symbol".  I am very grateful for the help ahead of time!!!!

```
/**
  * NAME: Mitchell Noble
  * DATE: November 3, 2015
  * FILE: lab10
  * COMMENTS: This program displays a loop using a celcius to fahrenheit conversion formula
  */

public class lab10
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // declare variables
      double fahrenheit;
      double celsius;

      value.setPrecision(2);
      celsius = 0;
      System.out.print("Celsius        Fahrenheit");
      while (celsius <= 15)
      {
         fahrenheit = 9 / 5 * celsius + 32;
         System.out.print(celsius + "             " + fahrenheit);
         celsius = celsius + 1;
      }
   } // close main
}
```

Comment: `value.setPrecision(2);` What is value there ?

Comment: As @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ pointed out, what is "value" here? Looks like you copied the statement from some online example. Replace "value.setPrecision()" with "fahrenheit.setPrecision()"

Comment: If they're declared as doubles, calling setPrecision won't work, they're primitives.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do floating point math with arbitrary precision? If so, you need to look at java's BigDecimal class:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

and do something like this:

```
BigDecimal celsiusValue = new BigDecimal("18");
BigDecimal farenheit = celsiusValue.multiply(new BigDecimal("1.8")).add(new BigDecimal("32"));
```

If you're just trying to format it to print out with two decimals, you can do it like this:

```
String toPrint = new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(celsius);
```

Answer (score -2):

value is an undefined variable.  In order to set the precision for your local variables:

```
fahrenheit.setPrecision(2);
celsius.setPrecision(2);
```

That will provide you with the desired precision on both the double variables.

Comment: You can't call methods on primitive doubles.